# NullObjectReferenceExeption that refers to a completely different part of the code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I`m currently working on my game project(https://github.com/sir1e/DL) and I have these exceptions that I have no clue how to fix, pls help. Knockback is a variable for knockback, but I don't need knockback for my player's attack, so I made it Vector2.zero.

I tried everything I can  do

Comment: Please so not post links as that link shows nothing we can use. Please add your code to your question as well as exact error and where it says the error is

Answer (score 0):

You really think someone is going to look through all this code? Just paste in the script that is causing the errors and then maybe also put in the Error Message here. But not your full project, It's just unnecessary work for others, so wasting others time, because your own one seems to be more important for you.
[image: Your Scripts]

Comment: This is not an answer. Your reminder is expedient but you should write it as a comment.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I can't make comments, as I don't have 50 Reputation.